# Exclude element from canvas to be saved to json (fabric.js)

Tags: javascript, json, fabricjs

I am using

```
 var jsonToPHP= JSON.stringify(canvas.toObject(['id','name']));
```

to save all from canvas to JSON.

I am also adding background image to canvas.

```
document.getElementById('imgLoader').addEventListener("change", function (e) {   var file = e.target.files[0];   var reader = new FileReader();   reader.onload = function (f) {
    var data = f.target.result;                    
    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
    var oImg = img.set({left: 0, top: 0, angle: 00,width:canvas.width, height:canvas.height,}).scale(1);
    oImg.set('selectable', false);
    canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({format: 'png', quality: 0.8});
    });   };   reader.readAsDataURL(file);

});
```

But i would like to exclude background image to be saved to JASON.

I vas googling for:

> Exclude element from canvas to be saved to json fabric.js

and i have got next:

> in the fabricjs docs there is a property for the Object class calles
>   'excludeFromExport'.
>
> Once set to true it should do exactly what you want.
>
> www.fabricjs.com/docs

I went to:

> Source: fabric.js, line 12350 excludeFromExport

And what now?

My knowlage is to less to get to result from this. Does any one can give more informations: maybe one example?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DEMO**

```js
document.getElementById('imgLoader').addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(f) {
        var data = f.target.result;
        fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function(img) {
            var oImg = img.set({
                left: 0,
                top: 0,
                angle: 00,
                width: canvas.width,
                height: canvas.height
            });
            canvas.setBackgroundImage(oImg).renderAll();
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
                format: 'png',
                quality: 0.8
            });
        });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
    serializeBgOverlay: false //to serialize background data toJson
});

canvas.backgroundColor = 'green';
canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
    radius: 50,
    stroke: 'red',
    fill: ''
}))
canvas.renderAll();

// override _toObjectMethod and if you want to serialize background , set serializeBgOverlay true, while canvas initialize
fabric.StaticCanvas.prototype._toObjectMethod = function(methodName, propertiesToInclude) {
    var data = {
        objects: this._toObjects(methodName, propertiesToInclude)
    };

    if (this.serializeBgOverlay) {
        fabric.util.object.extend(data, this.__serializeBgOverlay(methodName, propertiesToInclude));
    }
    fabric.util.populateWithProperties(this, data, propertiesToInclude);
    return data;
}

function exportToJson() {
    console.log(canvas.toJSON());
}
```

```css
canvas{
 border:2px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.16/fabric.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="imgLoader" accept="image/*"> <br>
<canvas id='c' width='400' height='400'></canvas>
<button onclick='exportToJson();'>ToJson</button>
```

Here I added a prototype of `_toObjectMethod()` , it will exclude background image of canvas toJson export.

Comment: Thank you.  I was working on other things today. I did not get any notification on my email address, that reply to my question was added. I will check tomorrow.

Comment: This problem has been reported as bug from a user on the issue tracker and a fix is planned. You will not need a special fix for this.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi wasn't aware of

Comment: happened like 2 days ago. coincidence.

Comment: I don't understand what is going on here.