# How to set background image from current canvas in fabric js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Im looking how to set background image from current canvas in fabric js

Is it possible to do? or please explain to me know how to do it.

I could do 1) 2) 5) though, I couldnt figure it out
I want to do number 3

1) import png image from pc
2) do something such as rotate, expand image
3) set background image it
4) do something again
5) export png image

i tried this

```
var object2 = new fabric.Circle({
left: 200,
  top: 200,
  radius: 30,
  fill: 'gray',
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 3
});

canvas.setBackgroundImage(object2, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
canvas.renderAll();
```

it works though the next one doesnt work after i upload an image.

```
var object = canvas.getActiveObject();
canvas.setBackgroundImage(object, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
canvas.renderAll();
```

i referred upload code from here
[How to upload an image to a canvas with Fabric.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715812/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-canvas-with-fabric-js)

thanks for in advance.

Comment: Please read the help center before posting.

Answer (score 0):

```
canvas.setBackgroundImage(obj)
```

Use this to set uploaded image as your canvas background. For more [Check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45159117/3551786)

Comment: thanks for the reply. though i want to do like this, 

var object = canvas.getActiveObject();
canvas.setBackgroundImage(object);
canvas.renderAll();

is it possible?

Comment: @kozimon yes you can set image or any fabric object

Comment: i could do it when i create object first though i couldnt do it when i upload image. Could you recognize any problems in here? (i added more description on the thread, please attach it)

Comment: @kozimon Check this [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45159117/3551786). Here you can upload from local and set it as a background